# Is it possible to do a feed forward in tensorflow without starting a session

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

I am new to tensorflow and i am using the object detection model.
I was wondering if there is a way to run my feed forward test file on the checkpoints without having to start the session every time as it takes so much time to start.

Comment: can you post some code as to show what you've done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, [tensorflow session](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/client/session_management) encapsulates the environment in which operations are executed, and tensors are evaluated. Can't run anything without it.